# Generating random simple math division problems

Tags: java, android, random, division, modulus

I'm making a simple Android app for my daughter so she can do math problems. I found it fairly easy to generate addition, subtraction and multiplication questions at random, however division is more tricky.

I don't want to get into decimals, so I have to check each is divisible without remainder. This is what I am working with...

```
public void genDivQuestion() {
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(divisible());
        answer = first / second;
}

public String divisible() {
        first = RandomNumGen.getRandIntBetween(2, 12);
        second = RandomNumGen.getRandIntBetween(2, 12);
        if (first % second == 0) {
            return first + " \u00F7 " + second + " = ?";
        } else {
            return "0";
        }
}
```

I'm not sure what to do at the line "return "0";". If I try calling divisible() to try again, the app just crashes.

This is the RandomNumGen class, which I appropriated from a beginner's book by James Cho:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumGen {

    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static int getRandIntBetween(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
        return rand.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound) + lowerBound;
    }

    public static int getRandInt(int upperBound) {
        return rand.nextInt(upperBound);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your error stack to the question

Comment: Could you post the code for RandomNumGen as well?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of drawing 2 random numbers and checking if they are divisible with each other, try the following:

```
first = someRandomNumber(2, 12);
second = someRandomNumber(2, 12);

showDivisionProblem(first * second, first)
```

Here the problem will ask you to divide `first * second` by `first`, where the answer should be `second`.

For example:

```
3 * 2 / 2 --> 6 / 2 = 3
```

No need to run in a loop until you find 2 good numbers. This way, the numbers will always be dividable.

**Edit:**

if it's important to limit the two operands by 12, then consider the following:

```
first = someRandomNumber(2, 12);
second = someRandomNumber(1, 12 / first);
```

where first is of type int.

In this case, if first is any value above 6, second is forced to be 1. 
If first is any value between 6 and 4, second can be 1 or 2
If first is 4, second can be 1, 2 or 3
etc.

Comment: Try again, stay in the range 2..12 for both operands.

Comment: although I don't think that's a good idea... if a child knows how to multiply 3 by 10, then should know how to divide 30 by 3.

Comment: This may produce 16/4 and misses 10/n.

Comment: I will give these ideas a shot. It's not imperative that the range is so limited, but my daughter is only four. On the other hand she is exceptionally smart :) Thanks.

Comment: 4 year olds can be exceptionally smart, especially if their dad makes them apps to study math ;)